# Extension Documentation with Sphinx

Tags: typo3, python-sphinx, typo3-6.2.x

I wrote the Documentation for my extension with Sphinx documentation.

It works fine and in my Backend the Extension looks good.

But if I publish the Extension to the TER my Documentation isn't listed... How can I achieve the linking in TER?

Comment: Just curious what does _rere_ do?

Comment: Just asking what is job of the extension, I installed it, but even have no idea how to make it working

Comment: :) okay isn't finished yet :) Only want to try publishing and adding the documentation 

but backend should work the most things allready its an extension for universities.

If I can add the documentation you will get some examples :)

Comment: how is the documentation written with sphinx published to docs.typo3.org?

Comment: Dunno, maybe you need to wait for rendering it never renders right after upload

Comment: Ah okay that should go automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see it's rendered now http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/rere/

A good habit is to publish extensions to TER with English localization in the documentation as default.

Comment: Yeah :) frist the extenaion should be finished then there will be time to translate :) thanka

Comment: It shouldn't be published if not finished, but I know that next will be better :)

Comment: I've got an additional question, when I have generated an phpdoc with api gen, is it possible to publish the phpdoc in the sphinx docu?

Comment: Please open a separate topic for additional questions.